# Добавление в регистрацию покемона

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Я хочу создать онлайн игру покемоны. И у меня появился вопрос, как сделать в регистрации картинку покемона, но при этом когда я его выбрал, чтоб он потом появился в моем профиле, но только не просто картинка, а покемон со статами, уровнем, жизнями и атаками, как это сделать? Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть таблица покемонов с их статами и описанием, есть таблица юзеров с их данными. При регистрации в специально отведенное поле у юзера, после выбора покемона, вносишь туда ID покемона, и у тебя будет  постоянная связка твоего юзера с покемоном, можно несколько выбирать покемонов, для этого не обязательно много полей делать у юзера, достаточно хранить ID например через запятую или пробел в одном поле.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос из разряда "хочу всё и сразу, помогите".
По теме: в форме регистрации делаете связь между покемонами из базы и тем, что пользователь выбирает(картинка). При успешной регистрации запись о выборе будет в базе и всё, дальше ей манипулируете.